# Automatically place cursor in omnibox / address bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, address-bar, omnibox

I am creating a `chrome extension` that sets the new tab page to my website (which is a replacement new tab page).

Once the redirect has occurred, I'd like the cursor to automatically be focused on the `omnibox` or `address bar`, so that the user can immediately start writing a URL or search query.

I'm sure this is possible because I have had chrome extensions in the past that allow this.

Anyone have any ideas how to go about it?

Comment: The cursor should be automatically focus on address bar, it's default behavior. So what do you want to do?

Comment: @HaibaraAi Because my extension redirects the user to a website, the address bar has that web address in it and is not focused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight URL bar using Chrome and Safari extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492399/highlight-url-bar-using-chrome-and-safari-extension)

Answer (score 2):

You're probably doing the new tab page replacement in a crude way - by intercepting a tab opening and redirecting it. In this scenario, as Haibara Ai mentions in a comment, it's not possible to focus on the omnibar.

Instead, you should create an [override page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) in the manifest:

```
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "newtab.html"
  },
```

This should be a local page, but you can embed your remote content using an iframe.

What's important is that override page will function the same as the normal one - the URL bar will be clear and the focus will be there by default.

---

Finally, think of the user experience when making a new tab reliant on remote content. You want the page to stay functional in case of a bad connection or offline browsing. Think of using [offline techniques](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline) to remedy this, or having a local webapp that just pulls information off your site but renders independently.