# Detect address bar focus of Chrome Browser from an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I need to develop a small browser **extension** for Chrome based on JavaScript. How to detect if the Chrome Browsers **address bar** got focused?
What I want to archive with the Chrome-extension: As soon as the address bar got focused a window will appear below the **bookmarks** bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take my web page focus to browser address bar using javascript / jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304774/take-my-web-page-focus-to-browser-address-bar-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: You can't do that using only extensions API. You can write a separate utility that can use the low-level OS functions and communicate with the extension via *nativeMessaging API*.