# Focus adress bar on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, pageload

I'm new to coding so this might be a very simple answer but I didn't find any answers on the web.

**Is it possible jump to the address when a page loads (simple HTML).**
Same function as CTRL+L or CMD+L in google chrome.
Is there a built in function?

- Google Chrome
- I have Javascript and Jquery
- Simple html page

Thanks in advance for all replies!

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304774/take-my-web-page-focus-to-browser-address-bar-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: I don't think it's possible.